# SOAPException IOException

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soap, oas

I'm a noob in java! I have a java Application in a OAS server, When I try to call a web service in another server return this excepción

```
[SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:IOException; msg=Connection timed out;targetException=java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]
```

I don't have idea what is the problem or the cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide more information? How are you making the call from the client? How is defined your service? Is the service taking too long to respond (as it is showing timed out)? Etc.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to connect to the wrong server, or the service is down, or a firewall or ACL is blocking your connection maybe. Check the URL and see if you can connect to the host and port from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same exception when calling WS from client. The problem was pretty simple (beside the fact that error message was not helpful at all) - there was a proxy server between the client and server, I had to add proxy settings (host, port) to the JVM (parameters -Dhttp.proxyHost=x.x.x.x -Dhttp.proxyPort=xxxx).